# How to JSON format an HTTP error response in webapp2

Tags: json, google-app-engine, error-handling, webapp2

I am using webapp2 for development in App Engine. What I would like to do is to send a custom JSON formatted response in case of an error. For example when the request length is larger that a threshold, to respond with HTTP 400 and response body

```
{'error':'InvalidMessageLength'}
```

In webapp2, there is the option to assign error handlers for certain exceptions. For example:

```
app.error_handlers[400] = handle_error_400
```

Where handle_error_400 is the following:

```
def handle_error_400(request, response, exception):
    response.write(exception)
    response.set_status(400)
```

When `webapp2.RequestHandler.abort(400)` is executed, the above code is executed.

How is it possible to have different response formats (HTML and JSON) dynamically based on the above setup? That is, how it is possible to call different versions of `handle_error_400` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a fully working example that demonstrates how to have the same error handler for all kind of errors and if your URL starts with `/json` then the response will be an `application/json` (use your imagination on how you could make a good use of the `request` object to decide what kind of response you should provide):

```
import webapp2
import json

def handle_error(request, response, exception):
  if request.path.startswith('/json'):
    response.headers.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    result = {
        'status': 'error',
        'status_code': exception.code,
        'error_message': exception.explanation,
      }
    response.write(json.dumps(result))
  else:
    response.write(exception)
  response.set_status(exception.code)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication()
app.error_handlers[404] = handle_error
app.error_handlers[400] = handle_error
```

In the above example you can easily test the different behaviours by visting the following URLs that will return a `404` which is the easiest error to test:

```
http://localhost:8080/404
http://localhost:8080/json/404
```

Comment: @ThanosMakris You're very welcome. Also if you are starting a new project you could check my [gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com) project where you can see in action JSON (http://gae-init.appspot.com/_s/user/), error handling (http://gae-init.appspot.com/404 or http://gae-init.appspot.com/_s/404) and many more goodies. If you have any questions your feedback is much appreciated and you can also write me in Greek :)

Comment: @ThanosMakris Consider porting you application to a gae-init fork. Once Lipis shaped the framework we have ported all our projects. Yesterday actually I ported the wepapp from my company. Flexibility, maintainability, and optimal as hell, definitely worths the time, at least investigating. Problems you already have or you might face as you grow big, already solved ;)